# Can any one tell me whats wrong in the attached json file

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to json. could nay one tell me what's wrong in attached json file

```
{
    "Study": [{
                "StudyAccountNumber": "050974",
                "ProtocolName": "1237.19_RO_01",
                "MSCCTProductVersion": "4.1.27",
                "MSCCTInstallationDate": "2016-01-05T07:51:26",
                "Site": [{
                            "id": "12345",
                            "SiteId": "12345",
                            "SystemId": "291215",
                            "CityName": "City",
                            "Country": "DE",
                            "PostalCode": "76544567",
                            "Province": "N/A",
                            "Street": "Street",
                            "PrimaryInvestigator": "PIName",
                            "Operators": [{
                                "Operator": [{
                                    "name": "inv",
                                    "OperatorUserName": "inv",
                                    "OperatorLastName": "N/A",
                                    "OperatorFirstName": "N/A",
                                    "OperatorRole": "N/A"
                                }]
                            }],
                            "FirstTransferDate": "N/A",
                            "LastTransferDate": "N/A",
                            "Subjects": [{
                                "SubjectCount": "5",
                                "Subject": [{
                                    "name": "72669",
                                    "SUBJECTID1": "72669",
                                    "AGE": "89",
                                    "GENDER": "Female",
                                    "HEIGHT": "96",
                                    "ETHNICITY": "OrientalsHongKongChinese",
                                    "VisitTrack": "N/A",
                                    "LastVisitOn": "12SEP2015",
                                    "LastVisit": "V4",
                                    "NextVisitOn": "04DEC2015",
                                    "NextVisit": "V5",
                                    "PatientState": "Created,Included,Randomized",
                                    "Visit": [{
                                        "name": "V1",
                                        "ActionType1": [{
                                            "ActionName": "MedicationWashoutCheck",
                                            "DateTime": "16MAR201500:00:39",
                                            "Operator": "inv",
                                            "ActionDetails1": "Abstinenceofrestrictedmedication:Yes  ",
                                            "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                            "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                            "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                        }],
                                        "ActionType2": [{
                                            "ActionName": "Pre-dosePFT",
                                            "DateTime": "16MAR201500:03:17",
                                            "Operator": "inv",
                                            "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at00:03:19",
                                            "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                            "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                            "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                        }],
                                        "ActionType3": [{
                                            "ActionName": "SalbutamolorAlbuterol",
                                            "DateTime": "16MAR201500:09:02",
                                            "Operator": "inv",
                                            "ActionDetails1": "SalbutamolorAlbuterolat16MAR201500:09:02",
                                            "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                            "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                            "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                        }],
                                        "ActionType4": [{
                                            "ActionName": "Post-dosePFT",
                                            "DateTime": "16MAR201500:20:23",
                                            "Operator": "inv",
                                            "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at00:20:25",
                                            "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.54LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:69%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                            "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:59%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                            "ActionDetails4": "Reversibility(ml):-83Reversibility(%):18"
                                        }],
                                        "ActionType5": [{
                                            "ActionName": "Inclusion",
                                            "DateTime": "16MAR201500:20:58",
                                            "Operator": "inv",
                                            "ActionDetails1": "PatientInclusion:Yes  ",
                                            "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                            "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                            "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                        }, {
                                            "name": "V2",
                                            "ActionType1": [{
                                                "ActionName": "MedicationWashoutCheck",
                                                "DateTime": "17MAR201506:00:55",
                                                "Operator": "inv",
                                                "ActionDetails1": "Abstinenceofrestrictedmedication:Yes  ",
                                                "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                                "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                            }],
                                            "ActionType2": [{
                                                "ActionName": "Pre-dosePFT",
                                                "DateTime": "17MAR201506:03:14",
                                                "Operator": "inv",
                                                "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at06:03:16",
                                                "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                                "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                            }],
                                            "ActionType3": [{
                                                "ActionName": "Randomization",
                                                "DateTime": "17MAR201506:03:50",
                                                "Operator": "inv",
                                                "ActionDetails1": "PatientRandomization:Yes  ",
                                                "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                                "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                            }],
                                            "ActionType4": [{
                                                "ActionName": "StudyMedication",
                                                "DateTime": "17MAR201506:04:46",
                                                "Operator": "inv",
                                                "ActionDetails1": "StudyMedicationat17MAR201506:04:46",
                                                "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                                "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                            }],
                                            "ActionType5": [{
                                                "ActionName": "PFT1h",
                                                "DateTime": "17MAR201507:06:03",
                                                "Operator": "inv",
                                                "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at07:06:05",
                                                "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                                "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                            }],
                                            "ActionType6": [{
                                                "ActionName": "PFT2h",
                                                "DateTime": "17MAR201508:06:03",
                                                "Operator": "inv",
                                                "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at08:06:05",
                                                "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                                "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                            }],
                                            "ActionType7": [{
                                                "ActionName": "PFT3h",
                                                "DateTime": "17MAR201509:06:03",
                                                "Operator": "inv",
                                                "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at09:06:05",
                                                "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                                "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                            }, {
                                                "name": "V4",
                                                "ActionType1": [{
                                                    "ActionName": "MedicationWashoutCheck",
                                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201506:02:00",
                                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                                    "ActionDetails1": "Abstinenceofrestrictedmedication:Yes  ",
                                                    "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                                    "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                                }],
                                                "ActionType2": [{
                                                    "ActionName": "Pre-dosePFT",
                                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201506:04:39",
                                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                                    "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at06:04:41",
                                                    "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                                    "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                                }],
                                                "ActionType3": [{
                                                    "ActionName": "StudyMedication",
                                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201506:05:26",
                                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                                    "ActionDetails1": "StudyMedicationat12SEP201506:05:26",
                                                    "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                                    "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                                }],
                                                "ActionType4": [{
                                                    "ActionName": "PFT1h",
                                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201507:06:43",
                                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                                    "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at07:06:45",
                                                    "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                                    "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                                }],
                                                "ActionType5": [{
                                                    "ActionName": "PFT2h",
                                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201508:06:43",
                                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                                    "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at08:06:45",
                                                    "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                                    "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                                }],
                                                "ActionType6": [{
                                                    "ActionName": "PFT3h",
                                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201509:06:43",
                                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                                    "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at09:06:45",
                                                    "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                                    "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                                }]
                                            }]
                                        }]
                                    }]
                                }]
                            }]
                        }
```

Comment: TL;DR; [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it? If there's something specifically wrong then share the error that you're seeing when parsing or using this json and you'll be more likely to get useful answers from others.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: Parse error on line 214:
...}]                           }]                      }
---------------------^
Expecting ',', ']', got 'EOF'
```

Pleaes refer to this http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake.
All brackets were not closed.

Below is the valid code for JSON.

```
{
    "Study": [{
        "StudyAccountNumber": "050974",
        "ProtocolName": "1237.19_RO_01",
        "MSCCTProductVersion": "4.1.27",
        "MSCCTInstallationDate": "2016-01-05T07:51:26",
        "Site": [{
            "id": "12345",
            "SiteId": "12345",
            "SystemId": "291215",
            "CityName": "City",
            "Country": "DE",
            "PostalCode": "76544567",
            "Province": "N/A",
            "Street": "Street",
            "PrimaryInvestigator": "PIName",
            "Operators": [{
                "Operator": [{
                    "name": "inv",
                    "OperatorUserName": "inv",
                    "OperatorLastName": "N/A",
                    "OperatorFirstName": "N/A",
                    "OperatorRole": "N/A"
                }]
            }],
            "FirstTransferDate": "N/A",
            "LastTransferDate": "N/A",
            "Subjects": [{
                "SubjectCount": "5",
                "Subject": [{
                    "name": "72669",
                    "SUBJECTID1": "72669",
                    "AGE": "89",
                    "GENDER": "Female",
                    "HEIGHT": "96",
                    "ETHNICITY": "OrientalsHongKongChinese",
                    "VisitTrack": "N/A",
                    "LastVisitOn": "12SEP2015",
                    "LastVisit": "V4",
                    "NextVisitOn": "04DEC2015",
                    "NextVisit": "V5",
                    "PatientState": "Created,Included,Randomized",
                    "Visit": [{
                        "name": "V1",
                        "ActionType1": [{
                            "ActionName": "MedicationWashoutCheck",
                            "DateTime": "16MAR201500:00:39",
                            "Operator": "inv",
                            "ActionDetails1": "Abstinenceofrestrictedmedication:Yes  ",
                            "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                            "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                            "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                        }],
                        "ActionType2": [{
                            "ActionName": "Pre-dosePFT",
                            "DateTime": "16MAR201500:03:17",
                            "Operator": "inv",
                            "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at00:03:19",
                            "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                            "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                            "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                        }],
                        "ActionType3": [{
                            "ActionName": "SalbutamolorAlbuterol",
                            "DateTime": "16MAR201500:09:02",
                            "Operator": "inv",
                            "ActionDetails1": "SalbutamolorAlbuterolat16MAR201500:09:02",
                            "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                            "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                            "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                        }],
                        "ActionType4": [{
                            "ActionName": "Post-dosePFT",
                            "DateTime": "16MAR201500:20:23",
                            "Operator": "inv",
                            "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at00:20:25",
                            "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.54LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:69%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                            "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:59%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                            "ActionDetails4": "Reversibility(ml):-83Reversibility(%):18"
                        }],
                        "ActionType5": [{
                            "ActionName": "Inclusion",
                            "DateTime": "16MAR201500:20:58",
                            "Operator": "inv",
                            "ActionDetails1": "PatientInclusion:Yes  ",
                            "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                            "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                            "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                        }, {
                            "name": "V2",
                            "ActionType1": [{
                                "ActionName": "MedicationWashoutCheck",
                                "DateTime": "17MAR201506:00:55",
                                "Operator": "inv",
                                "ActionDetails1": "Abstinenceofrestrictedmedication:Yes  ",
                                "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                            }],
                            "ActionType2": [{
                                "ActionName": "Pre-dosePFT",
                                "DateTime": "17MAR201506:03:14",
                                "Operator": "inv",
                                "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at06:03:16",
                                "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                            }],
                            "ActionType3": [{
                                "ActionName": "Randomization",
                                "DateTime": "17MAR201506:03:50",
                                "Operator": "inv",
                                "ActionDetails1": "PatientRandomization:Yes  ",
                                "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                            }],
                            "ActionType4": [{
                                "ActionName": "StudyMedication",
                                "DateTime": "17MAR201506:04:46",
                                "Operator": "inv",
                                "ActionDetails1": "StudyMedicationat17MAR201506:04:46",
                                "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                            }],
                            "ActionType5": [{
                                "ActionName": "PFT1h",
                                "DateTime": "17MAR201507:06:03",
                                "Operator": "inv",
                                "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at07:06:05",
                                "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                            }],
                            "ActionType6": [{
                                "ActionName": "PFT2h",
                                "DateTime": "17MAR201508:06:03",
                                "Operator": "inv",
                                "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at08:06:05",
                                "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                            }],
                            "ActionType7": [{
                                "ActionName": "PFT3h",
                                "DateTime": "17MAR201509:06:03",
                                "Operator": "inv",
                                "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at09:06:05",
                                "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                            }, {
                                "name": "V4",
                                "ActionType1": [{
                                    "ActionName": "MedicationWashoutCheck",
                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201506:02:00",
                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                    "ActionDetails1": "Abstinenceofrestrictedmedication:Yes  ",
                                    "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                    "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                }],
                                "ActionType2": [{
                                    "ActionName": "Pre-dosePFT",
                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201506:04:39",
                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                    "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at06:04:41",
                                    "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                    "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                }],
                                "ActionType3": [{
                                    "ActionName": "StudyMedication",
                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201506:05:26",
                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                    "ActionDetails1": "StudyMedicationat12SEP201506:05:26",
                                    "ActionDetails2": "N/A",
                                    "ActionDetails3": "N/A",
                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                }],
                                "ActionType4": [{
                                    "ActionName": "PFT1h",
                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201507:06:43",
                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                    "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at07:06:45",
                                    "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                    "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                }],
                                "ActionType5": [{
                                    "ActionName": "PFT2h",
                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201508:06:43",
                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                    "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at08:06:45",
                                    "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                    "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                }],
                                "ActionType6": [{
                                    "ActionName": "PFT3h",
                                    "DateTime": "12SEP201509:06:43",
                                    "Operator": "inv",
                                    "ActionDetails1": "BestFEV1at09:06:45",
                                    "ActionDetails2": "FEV1:-0.46LFVC:0.80LFEV1/FVC:50%PEF:571L/minFEF25-75:6.61L/s",
                                    "ActionDetails3": "%PredFEV1:50%%PredFVC:-84%%PredPEF:634%%PredFEF25-75:604%",
                                    "ActionDetails4": "N/A"
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```